# Redundant register values in GCC-compiled binary?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

Alright, so I'm trying to learn reverse engineering and x64 assembly. As an example I wrote this little test program in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int square(int num) {
        return num * num;
}

int main() {
        int ans = square(5);
        printf("%d", ans);
}
```

This results in the following assembly code for the `square` function:

```
push   rbp
mov    rbp,rsp
mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
imul   eax,eax
pop    rbp
ret
```

This seems kind of weird to me, as `edi` is the function argument, which I believe is then stored on the stack and loaded back into `eax`, where it is then multiplied? Why not skip lines 3 and 4 and just `imul edi, edi`?
So I opened up radare2 and did just that, but now the program returns seemingly random numbers, I'm guessing memory addresses?

[image: radare2 screenshot + patched binary running]

Can someone explain to me why GCC uses this seemingly redundant register, and what I did wrong trying to patch the binary?

Comment: How much optimization did you use?  (`-O3`?)

Comment: Ah, I just compiled it with default settings, output with O3 optimization makes much more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't enable optimizations, so you're looking at debug code. With `-O3`, the output is:

[image]

One note about your question, you *need* to assign to `eax`, because `eax` stores the return value in an x86 application.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. And I found out what the problem was with my patch: `edi` is later overwritten by the other argument to printf: the pointer to the actual format string. The return value of square should be in `esi`.

Comment: Which is fine, because `edi` is used to pass parameters. Keep in mind that `edi` and `esi` are the only registers that can run the `rep *sb` instructions, and so are good candidates for this. There are a whole bunch of conventions compilers use (almost) universally, if you really want to code assembly alongside the compiler you need to know them, or you'll generate invalid code.

Comment: Actually programming in assembly is probably a bit ambitious for now, at the moment I'm mostly just trying to learn how to read assembly code generated by the compiler. But thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.  You can easily copy/paste text from Godbolt's asm output pane.

Comment: But without the color formatting. It's okay if you don't like pictures, feel free to add your own picture-free answer if it will improve everyone else's lives.

Comment: Didn't see your reply at the time.  When I copy text from Godbolt, I sometimes separate blocks with a blank line, or just comment that asm.  That gives the same general value that color highlighting gave, but without being an image.